# Request better example on welcome page

Tags: discussion

Note: [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5184/3066) is the one currently appearing as the welcome page example.

I happened to look at the welcome page today. It shows a example question and its answers. In my opinion the question chosen is not good example. Here is why:

The question (which was probably chosen for its brevity) is a rather open-ended question asking for recommendations of an open-source substitute for Wolfram Workbench. This question, while acceptable, is hardly typical. I further think it encourages new users to ask questions of the "Is there a thingy to do X?" sort, which are often not high quality questions.

The two answers shown are essentially link-only answers (again chosen for brevity, the actual question has other more thoughtful answers). I fear this will encourage new users to think that kind of answer is typical and desired.

I request that a well-posed question involving a coding problem or concerning a one of the subtleties of *Mathematica* that have answers that are not links be substituted.

I accept that it is incumbent upon me to suggest some alternatives. How about

[Flatten command: matrix as second argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119/3066)
[What does the construct f[x_] := f[x] = ... mean?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2639/3066)
[What is a Mathematica packed array?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496/3066)
[Partitioning with varying partition size](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7511/3066)
[Replacement inside held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/3066)
[How do I extract the middle element(s) of a given list?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26650/3066)

It would be necessary to do some editing of the above to use them as the welcome page example, but since the current example is clearly edited, I don't think that should be considered an impediment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had a discussion with [Shog9](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/users/198/shog9) (SE employee) about this issue before the feature was rolled out publicly in January ([link for mods](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2790?m=7636671#7636671)). The reason for that rather poor example is because SE uses a highly simplified, one-algo-fits-all "logic" to choose the set of candidate questions for the about page (mods can pick one from this list). Some of the constraints are:

- The question must have more than one answer
- The question *and* the answers must each be under 400 characters
- The posts must not have any code (not even inline code), lists, LaTeX or images.
- Some other tag restrictions as well that I don't remember (perhaps min # of questions in the tag?)

Needless to say, these restrictions are extreme for our site — answers are seldom without code/images and 400 characters is too short. In all the 11k+ questions on the site, the chosen one is the *only* question that fit the above criteria.

He did say that they'd try to tweak the algorithm and relax it a bit to give us more options, but it doesn't look like they've done it and they've already moved on to other things by now. I know, it sucks for us, but it seems like this rather clumsy set of rules works pretty well for a good majority of the sites on the network and they're probably reluctant to make exceptions on a site-by-site basis.

Comment: Perhaps we can _fake_ a good question on purpose

Comment: @belisarius I doubt it. if the question and answer can fit in 2 tweets, then it most likely isn't a good question for the site...

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. You have certainly addressed my issues although not in the way I hoped for. I am very sorry to learn that examples are restricted by draconian rules which, as you point out, are almost guaranteed to produce an example unsuited for our site.

Comment: I've lifted the restriction on block elements (code, etc.) - you now have a reasonable number of choices. That said, be careful - posts with block elements can end up looking really awful when shoehorned into /about (the page layout doesn't adjust to accommodate them at all).

Comment: Thanks @Shog9. That's a decent list. I'll go through it  later today.